# Thread being locked up

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket

I am writing a **multithreaded** Java application which gets info from a `websocket` and `bufferized` it on a `LinkedList`, and I have another thread which gets this info from this linked list, like a queue, first in first out, and also I have a `Thread.sleep(1)` to make it **wait 1 millisecond** before it tries to get the info from the linked list again. Sometime I don't know what is happening but it seems to wait more than 1 millisecond after some hours, like the consumer thread is down or too slow. Is there any better alternative than `Thread.sleep`? Should I bufferize this info using another data structure?
By the way this `LinkedList` is inside a singleton so I can produce the info in one thread and consume in another.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. [Check out how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried solving the problem and ran into an obstacle? Paste the code you're having problems with to clarify!

Comment: Actually I am debbuging it for a week, and I dont knwo if I am using a correct Data Structure to handle buffers. Or Thread.sleep is not reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread.sleep is not accurate especially at 1ms resolution.  See [How accurate is Thread.sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736681/how-accurate-is-thread-sleep) and [What exactly is RTSJ, the Real-Time Specification for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582101/what-exactly-is-rtsj-the-real-time-specification-for-java)  You will need to look into real-time programming to achieve this.